# Loop is copying the columns in the wrong ranges

Tags: excel, vba, function, for-loop, range

I have made this code to create an output sheet where columns from different sheets are sorted by header name and pasted one after the other.

For some reason, it is not pasting the columns underneath each other, but instead overwriting each one with the next:

```
Dim ws As worksheet
Dim max_ws As worksheet
Dim output_ws As worksheet
Dim max_ws_header As Range
Dim output_ws_header As Range
Dim header_cell As Range
Dim cc As Long
Dim max_cc As Long
Dim output_header_counter As Long
Dim ws_header_counter As Long
Dim output_header_name As String
Dim ws_header_name As String


Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Sheets("indice").Delete
Sheets("aneca").Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

For Each ws In Worksheets
    ws.Rows(1).EntireRow.Delete
    ws.Columns.Hidden = False
Next ws

max_cc = 0

For Each ws In Worksheets
    cc = last_column_index(ws, 1)
    If cc > max_cc Then
        max_cc = cc
        Set max_ws = ws
    End If
Next ws

Sheets.Add.Name = "Output"
Set output_ws = Sheets("Output")

Set max_ws_header = max_ws.Range(max_ws.Cells(1, 1), max_ws.Cells(1, max_cc))
Set output_ws_header = output_ws.Range(output_ws.Cells(1, 1), output_ws.Cells(1, max_cc))

max_ws_header.Copy output_ws_header

For Each ws In Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> "Output" Then
        For output_header_counter = 1 To max_cc
            output_header_name = output_ws.Cells(1, output_header_counter).Value
            For ws_header_counter = 1 To max_cc
                ws_header_name = ws.Cells(1, ws_header_counter).Value
                If ws_header_name = output_header_name Then
                ws.Range(Cells(1, ws_header_counter), Cells(last_row_index(ws, ws_header_counter), ws_header_counter)).Copy _
                output_ws.Range(Cells(last_row_index(output_ws, output_header_counter) + 1, output_header_counter), Cells(last_row_index(ws, ws_header_counter), output_header_counter))
                End If
            Next ws_header_counter
        Next output_header_counter
    End If
```

The functions last_row_index and last_column_index are UDFs that I made as follows:

```
Function last_row_index(target_worksheet As worksheet, target_column_index As Long) As Long

    last_row_index = target_worksheet.Cells(Rows.Count, target_column_index).End(xlUp).Row
    
End Function

Function last_column_index(target_worksheet As worksheet, target_row_index As Long) As Long

    last_column_index = target_worksheet.Cells(target_row_index, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    
End Function
```

Here is an example of the output:

[image: output]

Comment: Be aware: using _Cells_ and _Range_ without indicating the worksheet the active worksheet is used.

Comment: @Shrotter Careful, that's only half the truth :) because `Cells()` is not always `ActiveSheet.Cells()`. Especially when using events, `Cells()` defaults to the worksheet in which scope the event is in. In this case `Cells()` is the same as `Me.Cells()` which can be different from `ActiveSheet.Cells()`. So that is actually why it is so dangerous using `Cells` or `Range` without specifying the worksheet. Because the default reference of those objects change with the scope the code is in, and if you copy the code into another scope it changes its behavior.

Comment: RE "*it is not pasting the columns underneath each other*": Note that columns are vertical, do you really want to paster them "underneath" each other?  Even assuming you mean to truncate them to only their vertical ranges with data, that would result in a single very long column of data.  Is that really what you want? (Normally people want to post rows underneath each other to produce a table or list-like formatting)

Comment: @Pᴇʜ thx for this additional information.

Comment: @RBarryYoung sorry for the poor explanation in the original post. What I meant to say is that, given that each column has its own color (each row should be all green, all red, etc), instead of pasting each row underneath each other, it is pasting the data all over the place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the solution, posting it here to close the question:

```
For Each ws In Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> "Output" And ws.Name <> "indice" And ws.Name <> "aneca" Then
        For row_index = 2 To last_row_index(ws, 1)
            output_counter = last_row_index(output_ws, 1)
            For column_index = 1 To last_column_index(ws, 1)
                ws_header = ws.Cells(1, column_index).Value
                For o_column_index = 1 To max_cc
                    output_header = output_ws.Cells(1, o_column_index).Value
                    If output_header = ws_header Then
                        ws.Cells(row_index, column_index).Copy output_ws.Cells(output_counter + 1, column_index)
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next o_column_index
            Next column_index
        Next row_index
    End If
Next ws
```

I made an output counter variable and made it find the last row each time it starts on a new row in the input sheets, and then I add +1 to it every time it pastes a row.